# PHPExcel - show top line when string breaks

Tags: phpexcel

I am using this code with PHPExcel to break a text into multiple lines in a cell (if needed).

```
$excelSheetRowNumber = 1;
$col = 'A';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col . $excelSheetRowNumber, $task->getName());
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col . $excelSheetRowNumber)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

The only problem is that if the text is wrapped, the last line is shown by default. I would like to have the *first* line to be shown.

To give you an example of what I mean, if I have this long text:

```
first line first line first line first line second line second line second line
```

And it gets broken up by PHPExcel like this:

```
first line first line first line first line 
second line second line second line
```

what I see in the cell when I open the spreadsheet is:

```
second line second line second line
```

as opposed to:

```
first line first line first line first line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, setting a cell to autowrap will also set the row to autofit. I'm unable to replicate your problem: what writer are you using?

However, you might try:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($col . $excelSheetRowNumber)
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Nice to be supported by one of the product developers :-)